# Problemas com escopo em php, alguém pode me ajudar por favor?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Eu tenho algumas classes, vou postar elas para pode então explicar o meu problema que é bem simples.

classe conexão com o banco de dados

```
<?php

/*
 * Gerencia conexões com bancos de dados,
 * usando arquivos de configuração
 */

/**
 * Description of base_dao
 *
 * @author willian.rodrigues
 */
final class tconnection {
    /*
     * Não existirão instâncias de base_dao
     * por isso marquei o contrutor como privado
     */

    private function __construct() {
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param String $name Nome do banco de dados
     * Verifica se exste arquivo de configuração para ele,
     * e instancia o objeto PDO correspondente.
     */

    public static function open($name = 'mysql_dgnetwork') {
        try{
            $option = array(
                // mantem a conexão com o banco sempre aberta para o usuário
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,

                // define PDO::FETCH_ASSOC como padrão de retorno
                PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => pdo::FETCH_ASSOC,

                // define para que o PDO lance exceções na ocorrência de erros
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
            );

            /*
             * Verifica se existe arquivo de configuração para ele
             * e instancia o objeto PDO correspondente.
             */
            if (file_exists("dao_config/{$name}.ini")) {
                // lê o INI e retorna um array
                $db = parse_ini_file("dao_config/{$name}.ini");
            } else {
                // se não existir, lança um erro
                throw new Exception("Arquivo '$name' não encontrado");
            }

            // lê as informações contidas no arquivo
            $user = isset($db['user']) ? $db['user'] : NULL;
            $pass = isset($db['pass']) ? $db['pass'] : NULL;
            $name = isset($db['name']) ? $db['name'] : NULL;
            $host = isset($db['host']) ? $db['host'] : NULL;
            $type = isset($db['type']) ? $db['type'] : NULL;
            $port = isset($db['port']) ? $db['port'] : NULL;

            /*
             * Descobre qual o tipo do driver
             * de banco de dados a ser utilizado.
             */
            switch ($type) {
                case 'mysql':
                    $port = $port ? $port : 3306;
                    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};port={$port};dbname={$name}", $user, "", $option);
//                    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};port={$port};dbname={$name}", $user, "");
                    break;
                case 'pgsql':
                    $port = $port ? $port : 5432;
                    $conn = new PDO("pgsql:dbname={$name}; user={$user}; password={$pass}; host=$host;port={$port}");
                    break;                    
                default :
                    throw Exception("Não foi possível conectar no banco de dados");
            }

            // retorna o atributo instanciado
            return $conn;
        } catch (PDOException $erro) {
//            $mensagem = $erro->getMessage();
//            //echo $mensagem;
//            //SALVA NO ARQUIVO DE LOG O ERRO
//            $dir = getcwd() . "/Logs//";
//            error_log(date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "|\n $mensagem|\r\n\r\n", 3, $dir . "DBconectionPDO.log");            
        } catch (Exception $erro) {

        }
    } // final do método open


}
```

base_dao bem simples

```
 <?php

require_once '/xampp/htdocs/DGNetwork/model/persistence/dao/tconnection.class.php';

/**
 * Description of base_dao
 *
 * @author willian.rodrigues
 */
abstract class base_dao {

    // funções abstratos
    abstract public function salvar(Object $obj);
//    abstract public function deletar(Object $obj);
//    abstract public function atualizar(Object $obj);
//    abstract public function selecionar(Object $obj);

}

?>
```

uma classe que persiste uma vo -  neste caso quero apenas fazer um select

```
<?php

require_once '/xampp/htdocs/DGNetwork/model/persistence/dao/base_dao.class.php';

/**
 * Description of estado_dao
 *
 * @author willian.rodrigues
 */
class estado_dao {
    // construtor
    public function __construct() {
        echo 'Instancia de base_dao construida com sucesso';
    }

    // destrutor
    public function __destruct() {
        ;
    }    

    // funções
    public function salvar(\Object $obj) {
        // tabela estática
    }

    public function pesquisar($sigla) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM estado WHERE sigla = ?";

        // recupera uma referência de connection
        $conn = tconnection::open();

        // prepara a query
        $query = $conn->prepare($sql);

        // configura os parâmetros
        $query->bindValue(1, $sigla);

        // executa a query
        $query->execute();

        // acessa e retorna o resultado
        $rs = $query->fetch();
        return $rs;
    }

    public function pesquisar_all() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM estado ORDER BY nome ASC";

        // recupera uma referência de connection
        $conn = tconnection::open();

        print_r($conn);

        // prepara a query
        $query = $conn->prepare($sql);

        // executa a query
        $query->execute();

        // acessa e retorna o resultado
        $rs = $query->fetchAll();
        return $rs;
    }    


}


//$e = new estado_dao();
//$estado = $e->pesquisar_all();
//
//foreach ($estado as $est) {
//    echo $est['sigla'];
//    echo '<br />';
//    echo $est['nome'];
//}
```

observem no final do código acima, nas linhas comentadas.
Se decrementar elas, ele busca n banco e exibe no banco o resultado normalmente.

agora a classe onde se passa o problema
Aqui o problema, na minha opnião é de escopo.
Se alguém poder me ajudar, eu ficaria muito agradecido.

```
<?php

require_once  '/xampp/htdocs/DGNetwork/model/persistence/dao/estado_dao.class.php';


/**
 * Description of estado_service
 *
 * @author willian.rodrigues
 */
class estado_service {
    // construtor
    public function __construct() {
        ;
    }

    // destrutor
    public function __destruct() {
        ;
    }    

    /**
     * 
     * @return array estado_vo
     */
    public function get_all_estado() {
        $estado_dao = new estado_dao();
        $estado = $estado_dao->pesquisar_all();
        return $estado;
    }
}

$e = new estado_service();
$estado = $e->get_all_estado();
echo 'cheguei aqui';
foreach ($estado as $est) {
    echo $est['sigla'];
    echo $est['nome'];
}
```

no meu navegador, o seguinte erro aparece:

> Instancia de base_dao construida com sucesso Fatal error: Call to a
>   member function prepare() on a non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\DGNetwork\model\persistence\dao\estado_dao.class.php
>   on line 55

Comment: Poderia evidenciar a linha do erro?

Comment: Sua chamada de conexão da classe estado_dao não está sendo corretamente instanciada. Porém há varias chamadas, como o @rray sugeriu, indique onde fica a linha 55, ou dentro de qual metodo da classe estado_dao.

Comment: Uma dica é você usar sempre nas classes, o padrao [Camel Case](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase), assim fica mais legivel seu codigo.

Comment: isso mesmo.
    public function pesquisar_all() 
   $query = $conn->prepare($sql);

Comment: Parece que o $conn devia estar no escopo da classe service.

Comment: Se `$conn` é inválido o problema é no `tconnection::open();`. Você não declarou nenhuma 'variável' como membro de classe, estão todas como variáis locais dos métodos.

Comment: vi que vcs já matara, o problema.

Comment: Mas será que alguém me ajuda com uma solução.

Comment: Você precisa verificar porque a conexão falhou, pode ser usuário e senha incorretos, database incorreta, porta etc.

Comment: não amigo.
COmo eu disse acima, o teste na camada DAO trouxe os dados e exibiram.
A questão foi quando eu trouxe o texte para a camada de Serviço.
Se vc reparar no código estado_dao.class.php acima, verá os testes no final, comentado.

Comment: user8045
É isso mesmo, devia estar, mas imagina, esto usando o padrão de projeto 3 camadas,onde o controller conversa com o service, o service com o vo e com o DAO, Ai não teria logia eu trazer ele para o service, senão eu não iria fazer o DAO.
A minha idéia com esse padrão é deixar as responsabilidades muito bem definidas.
Por favor gente, foca um pouquinho para ajudar o amigo aqui.
hehehe
Deus vai dar em dobro para vcs.

Comment: @user8045 não entendi seu último comentário. `public function pesquisar_all() {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM estado ORDER BY nome ASC";
$conn = tconnection::open();
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);` se linha 55 for `$query = $conn->prepare($sql)` `$conn` não é um objeto PDO.

Comment: ta bom
A minha classe estado_dao.class.php funciona.
No final dela, da classe estado_dao.class.php, eu fiz um teste.
$e = new estado_dao();
$estado = $e->pesquisar_all();

foreach ($estado as $est) {
    echo $est['sigla'];
    echo '<br />';
    echo $est['nome'];
}

Ai funcionou como esperado.
Isso me fez pensar imediatamente  que o problema estava relacionado ao escopo.

Comment: se o problema é escopo então defina namespaces e utilize um método  autoload

Comment: Olá Marcelo Bonus.
Eu pensei nisso, mas não entendi bem o porque tenho de fazer e nem como fazer nesse caso.
COnsegue me ajudar não